# Cannot ping between computers, but I can connect (only one way though)

Tags: ssh, connection, firewall, ping

I am new using Linux, so I would really appreciate a simple as possible answer.

I cannot ping between two computers, neither to nor from. I can ssh from one computer to another, but not the other way around.

I would be very grateful if I can get some direction as to what I might have to do in order to fix this.

The computer to which I cannot connect is Ubuntu 10.4 with wireless Internet (but I can connect to other from it), while the other one is a Mac OS.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you use the 'edit' link to add a short description of how each computer is connected to the internet (e.g., wireless router, etc)

Comment: Please provide more info on your situation.  What OS's are you running on each machine?  Are you connected through wireless or do you have a wired connection or both?  Are you machines connected through a router, access point, switch?

Comment: From one computer, run `traceroute -n 192.0.2.34` where 192.0.2.34 is the IP address of the other computer. This will reveal your IP address. If that really bothers you, consistently munge the numbers, leaving anything that begins with `192.168.` or `172.16.` or `10.` alone (they're private addresses).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ssh in both ways, you have to install the package **openssh-server** on both computers, to handle incoming ssh requests. This can be installed via the Ubuntu Software Center or using the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I installed it, but I still can't ssh. I get the following message: ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.194 port 22: Operation timed out

Comment: check the firewall in the one u cant do the ssh: and check if the service is runing service ssh status / start

Comment: Ok, I disabled my firewall, and when checking if my service is running I got   status: Env must be KEY=VALUE pairs. I'm trying to figure out what that means...

Comment: plz update ur question , about pinging